# Faster way to update an empty dataframe using the information from two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

I  have two dataframes: df_a and df_b (each having a total of 1,000,000 rows).

1. df_a has two columns: uniqueID, start_time
2. df_b has two columns: uniqueID, end_time

My objective is to generate a dataframe (df_final) with following columns:

- uniqueID, start_time, end_time

**df_final** **must contains all the data from df_a** (i.e. uniqueID, start_time). For each (uniqueID, start_time) in **df_final**, end_time must be taken from **df_b** corresponding to same uniqueID. df_b have multiple end_time for each uniqueID. For each uniqueID, *end_time closest to start_time must be considered* for **df_final["end_time"]**. In case, no such closest end_time is available in df_b, then df_final["end_time"] must be NULL.

**My approaches:** 
Approach 1:

```
#define a function
def get_end_date(uniqueID, start_time):
    sub_sectiondata = df_b[(df_b['uniqueID']==uniqueID) & (df_b["end_time"]>start_time)]
    if len(sub_sectiondata) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return min(sub_sectiondata["end_time"])
```

Then apply the above function on df_a.

```
df_a['end_time'] = df_a.apply(lambda x: get_end_date(x['uniqueID'], x['start_time']), axis=1)
```

Approach 2:

```
df = df_a.copy()

for row in df.itertuples():
    sub_sectiondata = df_b[(df_b['uniqueID']==row.uniqueID) & (df_b["end_time"]>row.start_time)]
    if len(sub_sectiondata)>0:
        df_final = df_final .append({'uniqueID':row.uniqueID, 'start_time':row.start_time, 'end_time': min(sub_sectiondata["end_time"])}, ignore_index = True)

    else:
        df_final = df_final .append({'uniqueID':row.uniqueID, 'start_time':row.start_time, 'end_time': None}, ignore_index = True)
```

In both the approaches, I am getting the desired result, but the time taken to execute this is very high. It increases linearly (for every 10000 records, it takes approx 20 minutes). So for 1000000, it will be around 33 hours to complete which is huge. So is there any other method in python to handle this? Any help in this regard from the community?

Comment: Have you tried profiling to see where the bottleneck is ?

Comment: How about, you first cleanup df_b to leave only one value per UniqueID (using the earliest end_time), then use inbuilt pandas methods to join/merge the dataframes. 
This assumes that the end_time is always bigger than start_time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating by rows over dataframes is known to be a slow operation. Here the magic word is `merge_asof`: it allows to select a row from a second dataframe immediately after a row in a first one, or having a numeric or date value nearest to the first one.

So if you want the end_time closest to start_time, you can do:

```
df_final = pd.merge_asof(df_a.sort_values('start_time'), df_b.sort_values('end_time')
    , left_on='start_time', right_on='end_time',
    by='unique_id', direction='nearest')
```

But this would allow an end_time before the start_time. If you want to ensure `end_time >= start_time` you should use `direction='forward'`:

```
df_final = pd.merge_asof(df_a.sort_values('start_time'), df_b.sort_values('end_time')
    , left_on='start_time', right_on='end_time',
    by='unique_id', direction='forward')
```

Comment: Thank you very much Serge for the quick answer. It really helped me a lot, otherwise it was taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the logic takes up a lot of time because Pandas has to look over the whole dataframes several times. Try profiling to see what takes a long time (https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html + https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/ ).

What you can try is:

- copy A
- add a columns *end_time* with Null values
- then iterate over B and if *end_time* is lower than the corresponding one in A with the same id you replace it.

That way you are only iterating over B once. This could be faster but it needs to be checked. If you provide me with an example dataset I can give it a shot.

I don't know if dataframes are the most efficient datastructure speedwise. Maybe using Numpy arrays directly it could be faster. If you are really desperate, Cython could be a way to speed things up as well but I have no experience with it.